# How to see exact strong references on the particular object at the runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, profiling, profiler

Got quite complicated WPF control here.

Under certain (well-known) conditions it promotes memory leakage.

But those popular memory profilers like dotTrace or elseones fail to discover the source of leak.

So my question is: could I somehow see the list of actual references on the given alive object? Is there such a tool?

Comment: Could you please provide some details how it fails to discover the source of the leak?
btw, dotTrace is a performance (not memory) profiler, may be it is the root of a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've typically found that Redgate ANTS is very good at tracing these references to their roots. And no disclaimer, I don't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

dotTrace is not a memory profiler, you need to use dotMemory instead for resolving memory issues (if talk about JetBrains products).